# How to Add URL Suffix

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I just want to ask that how do i add html suffix to each url of my site using htaccess?

A url like this:

www.mysite.com/index.php?hello/world

should become

www.mysite.com/index.php?hello/world.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1\.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to turn on **MultiViews**. Simply add the following line to a `.htaccess` file in the directory (or httpd.conf). Note that `Options All` does NOT turn on MultiViews, you need to explicitly turn it on.

```
Options +MultiViews
```

See the MultiViews section in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/content-negotiation.html for more info on what it does and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#options for more info on options.